# Injective endomorphism on a finite field is surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Can you guys give me any hint on how to prove(or disprove): any injective endomorphism on a finite field is also surjective?

Comment: An injective self-map has image the same size as the domain hence...

Comment: Hint: it has nothing to do with fields.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure this doesn't even require the endomorphism property,  just a general property of  injective maps from a finite set to itself.   Use the pigeonhole principle.